# VueJs reference selected object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to display a fullName function using selected value

HTML :

```
<div id="test">
<h1>{{ sayHi }}</h1>

<select v-model="selected">
   <option v-for="person in persons" v-bind:value="person.about">
   {{ person.lname }}
   </option>
</select>
<p> {{ selected }} </p>
```

JS

```
New Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    selected : '',
    persons: [
      { fname: 'Foo' ,
        lname : 'Foo2',
        about : 'loren ipsum'},
      { fname: 'Bar' ,
        lname:'Bar2',
        about: 'dolor met'}
    ]  
  },
  computed :{
    sayHi : function() {
      return this.fname + " " + this.lname
    }
  }
})
```

h1 should return based on selected object value,
this code returns undefined,(doesnt run at all if I pass in selected as arg) although the other parts work.Im not sure how to get the computed function to reference the selected object?

Edit:After using the great suggestions,Added a codepen for anyone else who is just starting:

https://codepen.io/2f2f/pen/rQdKKw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code returns `undefined` because there is no `this.fname`, nor `this.lname` - it refers to `data` object, which has only `selected` and `persons`.

You can use selected as holder for person from the loop, so in your method you can get person first and last names, but you need to modify bind value.

Try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    selected : '',
    persons: [
      { fname: 'Foo' ,
        lname : 'Foo2',
        about : 'loren ipsum'},
      { fname: 'Bar' ,
        lname:'Bar2',
        about: 'dolor met'}
    ]  
  },
  computed :{
    sayHi : function() {
      return this.selected.fname + " " + this.selected.lname
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="test">
<h1>{{ sayHi }}</h1>

<select v-model="selected">
   <option v-for="person in persons" v-bind:value="person">
   {{ person.lname }}
   </option>
</select>
<p> {{ selected.about }} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fname` and `lname` are not defined in `data`, so `this.fname` and `this.lname` are always undefined; You need to find the selected person object first based on the `selected` value, and then compute the full name from the `fname` and `lname`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    selected : '',
    persons: [
      { fname: 'Foo' ,
        lname : 'Foo2',
        about : 'loren ipsum'},
      { fname: 'Bar' ,
        lname:'Bar2',
        about: 'dolor met'}
    ]  
  },
  computed: {
    sayHi: function() {
      var selectedP = this.persons.find(p => p.about === this.selected)
      return selectedP ? selectedP.fname + " " + selectedP.lname : ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <h1>{{ sayHi }}</h1>

  <select v-model="selected">
     <option v-for="person in persons" v-bind:value="person.about">
     {{ person.lname }}
     </option>
  </select>
  <p> {{ selected }} </p>
</div>
```